# DSC and thermodynamic states

Tags: thermodynamics

During a DSC measurement, with changing temperatures of a sample, esp one undergoing a chemical reaction (ie oxidation, combustion)- the system undergoes changes in volume and pressure within. I am confusing Isobaric and Isochoric processes- but how do I measure $C_p$ or $C_v$ when I am observing clear changes in volume and internal pressure of molecules?